git pull on webserver from github via SSH
I created a website locally and pushed the files via ssh to github. For that I generated an ssh-key  and had now issues. No I am trying to pull those files on my webserver (connection via ssh). But I am not able to get the permission to pull from github. Following my output from ssh -vT git@github.com:
ssh-w018a58e@dd45026:/www/htdocs/w018a58e$ ssh -vT git@github.com
OpenSSH_8.9p1 Ubuntu-3ubuntu0.6, OpenSSL 3.0.2 15 Mar 2022
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: include /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/*.conf matched no files
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 21: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to github.com [140.82.121.4] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug1: identity file /.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk type -1
debug1: identity file /.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: identity file /.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /.ssh/id_ed25519_sk type -1
debug1: identity file /.ssh/id_ed25519_sk-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /.ssh/id_xmss type -1
debug1: identity file /.ssh/id_xmss-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_8.9p1 Ubuntu-3ubuntu0.6
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version babeld-32c28593
debug1: compat_banner: no match: babeld-32c28593
debug1: Authenticating to github.com:22 as 'git'
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /.ssh/known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts: No such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ssh-ed25519
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY received
debug1: Server host key: ssh-ed25519 SHA256:+DiY3wvvV6TuJJhbpZisF/zLDA0zPMSvHdkr4UvCOqU
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /.ssh/known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts: No such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug1: Host 'github.com' is known and matches the ED25519 host key.
debug1: Found key in /.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug1: ssh_packet_send2_wrapped: resetting send seqnr 3
debug1: rekey out after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: ssh_packet_read_poll2: resetting read seqnr 3
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: rekey in after 134217728 blocks
debug1: Will attempt key: /.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Will attempt key: /.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Will attempt key: /.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk
debug1: Will attempt key: /.ssh/id_ed25519
debug1: Will attempt key: /.ssh/id_ed25519_sk
debug1: Will attempt key: /.ssh/id_xmss
debug1: Will attempt key: /.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,sk-ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-512-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,sk-ssh-ed25519@openssh.com,sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa>
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Trying private key: /.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Trying private key: /.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk
debug1: Trying private key: /.ssh/id_ed25519
debug1: Trying private key: /.ssh/id_ed25519_sk
debug1: Trying private key: /.ssh/id_xmss
debug1: Trying private key: /.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).

My questions:

what are the necessary setup steps on a server to get ssh going?
in my .ssh/key I copied the public key which I used on github. Is that correct?
Do I need to setup a config file in .ssh?
Or is it also possible to push directly to the webserver?

Thanks for any help, tips and advice. Really stuck here and I feel like it's an easy solution.
Coded locally, pushed to github via ssh. Ssh connection to webserver, cannot pull files from github.

You say "I generated an ssh-key", There are always two ssh keys, public and private.

https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+%5Bssh%5D+Permission+denied+publickey

Did you registered ssh key in github?
private key should be located on your host, public key on github, Which of the listed keys were key you have generated?

Yes I did, registered the public key on my github and the private key is on my local computer.

Do I need to put my private key also on my webserver?

@TobiasSchmid No, the private key must never leave the device where it was generated. The public key can be published everywhere.

Yes thats also how I understood it. It still does not make click, but I think its an easy solution here. I created to different keys (private & public), for ssh connection to github and my webserver. Do I have to use the same key here to enable the connection from my webserver to github?

@TobiasSchmid Yes, the usual practice is one keypair per client device, except when you need a few different keypairs to connect to one hosting/server (like Github) under different accounts.

Okay. So to summit:
Ssh connection to web server (private key on laptop, public key on provider)
Ssh connection to GitHub (private key on laptop, public key on GitHub)
I can connect to my server via ssh, and push to GitHub via ssh. But cannot pull on my web server from GitHub.
Do I need to setup a config for ssh on my server to pull from GitHub?

@TobiasSchmid On the server you need to generate another keypair and upload its public key to GitHub; then you can pull/push from the server. A different solution is to pass ssh-agent (if you know what it is and know how to load a private key to it) connection to the server (ssh -A server) and use your laptop's private key at the server; this is only recommended only if you trust the server's admins (root) because they can read your private key from laptop-server ssh connection.

Yes! Thats it, no it's working. I do trust the server, but I was a bit afraid of creating a private key and putting it on a remote server. But now it's working and I can pull from github on my server. Cheers!

@TobiasSchmid The private key must never leave the device where it was generated. If you gonna to generate a new keypair for the server generate it at the server. Push its public key to GitHub (not necessary directly: you can copy the public key to the laptop). But if forwarding agent works for you that's also a good way. Good luck!
